# How to increase my algo speed to load an image using tkinter?

Tags: python, image, tkinter, python-imaging-library

i have two different functions one load the images in a linear manner and the other load the images recursively but both are taking the same time.

Q. is anything wrong with my recursive function.

```
def load_image(window, arr, lb, ub):
if lb < ub:

    if ub - lb == 1:
        arr[lb] = ImageThumbnail(window, os.path.join(img_path, img_name[lb]), (100, 50))
        return

    mid = (lb + ub) // 2

    load_image(window, arr, lb, mid)
    load_image(window, arr, mid, ub)


def load_image2(window, arr):

for i, img in enumerate(arr):
    images[i] = ImageThumbnail(window, os.path.join(img_path, img_name[i]), (100, 50))
```

Comment: The slowest part of your code is most likely the actual image loading, not how you iterate over a list or in what order. Why use a recursive function when you can just iterate over a list?

Comment: I think that dividing the array and accessing each element in recursion should increase the function speed than linear iterating.

Comment: Using a recursive function to effectively just iterate over a list is almost certainly going to be vastly slower than just using a for loop. The overwhelming majority of time is taken by generating the images so the difference between the two is not noticeable, optimising that part of your code would produce more benefit or some asynchronous solution if the issue is IO

Comment: if you are saying (Iain Shelvington) both functions will take equal time if the issue is IO then what should I do to increase the speed.

Comment: Buy faster hardware ...